# Deserialize enum from both Integer and String in Java

Tags: java, enums, jackson, deserialization

I am adding a new code logic, using CDC (capture data change) events.
A `status` field coming from the DB is represented as an int and should be deserialized into an enum.
This is the enum:

```
public enum Status {

    ACTIVE(21),
    CANCELLED(22),
    EXPIRED(23),
    FAILED(24),
    PAUSED(25);

    private static final Map<Integer, Status> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (val value : Status.values()) {
            if (map.put(value.getId(), value) != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate id: " + value.getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public static Status getById(Integer id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

    private Integer id;

    Status(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

1. The enum can't be "out of the box" serialized from Integer since it
   is not starting from 0 (receiving `index value outside legal index range` exception).
2. Today we already have a flow that is receiving a String (e.g. "ACTIVE") and deserializing it successfully. I do not want to change/harm this capability.

I've tried to add `@JsonCreator` here:

```
@JsonCreator
public static SubscriptionStatus getById(Integer id) {
    return map.get(id);
}
```

But now it is impossible to deserialize String anymore. I prefer to have a simple solution rather than creating a custom deserializer for it (I assume there should be one).

Comment: Did you try using `Object` and check whether you get `String` or `Number`/`Integer`?

Comment: It is deserialized into an Integer, but I am still not sure what should I do with it?

Comment: Well, if it is an integer you need to treat that as the id and do the lookup accordingly. If you'd get a string you could assume it's the name (you might want to check if it could be the id encoded as an integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Status get(Object reference) {
  if( reference instanceof Number num) {
    return getById(num.intValue());
  } else if( reference instanceof String str) {
    //the string might contain the id as well, e.g. "21" for ACTIVE
    //so you might want to check the string for this, if this is expected
    return Enum.valueOf(Status.class, str);
  }
        
  return null;
}
```

This basically takes a value of any type, checks what it is and resolves the enum value accordingly.